# Why context_info can fail?

Tags: sql-server, delphi, context-info

I am using context_info to simulate a global variable, I use it in this context.

I have scripts made up of several batches, I set a global variable at the beginning (`123` in the example) and then after all the batches I use that number to populate a log table.

Now this works, but today it failed on one machine, I cannot figure why. Is there a reason why context_info should not work? I tried to manually replace `context_info` with `123` and the script was succesful. The script was run from a Delphi application.

```
DECLARE @GlobalInteger binary(128)
SET @GlobalInteger =cast(123 as binary(128))
SET CONTEXT_INFO @GlobalInteger 
GO

BATCH 1
GO

...

BATCH N
GO

INSERT INTO TABLE_LOG VALUES (cast(context_info() as INT)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some Remarks in the [`CONTEXT_INFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180125.aspx) documentation:

> Multiple active result sets (MARS)
>   enables applications to run multiple
>   batches, or requests, at the same time
>   on the same connection. When one of
>   the batches on a MARS connection runs
>   SET CONTEXT_INFO, the new context
>   value is returned by the CONTEXT_INFO
>   function when it is run in the same
>   batch as the SET statement. The new
>   value is not returned by the
>   CONTEXT_INFO function run in one or
>   more of the other batches on the
>   connection, unless they started after
>   the batch that ran the SET statement
>   completed

There are also some explanations on how the value propagates to the various views exposing it (sys.dm_exec_requests, sys.dm_exec_sessions and CONTEXT_INFO itself), see Using [Session Context Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189252.aspx). In some places the information is visible right away, in other places is visible only after the batch has completed.